# Stateful service fabric service - replication of files changed in the disk

Tags: sqlite, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

If I embed an SQLite db (or any big file) in a stateful Service Fabric Service or Actor process, (or even azure app service)  how the replication works in the background?
Azure  will try to copy the whole file when it detects changes, or disk sectors only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure will try to copy the whole file when it detects changes, or disk sectors only?

No, stateful services only replicate data placed on reliable collections, you should **not** expect changed files to be replicated across nodes, whenever a new instance of your service is created, the original file is copied to the new node and you won't have access to the modified files. You shouldn't persist file in the node disk, for this you should use a persisted storage like Azure Blob Storage, or attach a File Share to the nodes.

> How the replication works in the background?

I think you misunderstood the concept of reliable collections and stateful services, I recommend you take a look on this docs to have a clear view on how it works: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections

**Suggestion**:

If you want to rely on SF data management and replication features, I would recommend you store your data in the reliable collections instead of using the SqlLite. If fits your requirements.

***Update:***

At Build 2018, the SF team announced the plans to support two versions of 'reliable' volumes, one will be based o Azure files, same as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-volume-logging-drivers) and the other will be based on reliable collections, that will replicate changed files, the later, is not released yet. If you can wait, I think these feature will be suitable for your needs.

Comment: It seems the  Service Fabric Azure Files Volume Driver (preview) 
 is the way to go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-volume-logging-drivers

Comment: There are two reliable volumes on SF roadmap, one is the one you described, the other is like a reliable collection for files, not sure the release dates, I've update the answer with these.

Comment: Yes, the second option (Service Fabric volume disk)  would be more performant https://youtu.be/0ab2wIGMbpY?t=1824